# Java8: Use filters/predicates along with disjunction

Tags: collections, java-8, predicate

There are two maps with same structure say map1 and map2 having structure as `Map<String, Boolean>`.

Map 1 contains following items:
`("i1", True),("i2", True), ("i3", False), ("i4", True)`
Map 2 contains following items:
`("i1", True),("i2", False), ("i3", True), ("i5", True)`

I want two kinds of information:
`Information1: map1TrueMoreThanMap2True = 2`
The map1TrueMoreThanMap2True is 2 because we are comparing map entries.
In this case the diff between map1 and map2 is:
`Map1 - ("i2", True),("i4", True)`

`Information2: map1FalseMoreThanMap2False = 1`
In this case the diff between map1 and map2 is:
`Map1 - ("i3", False)`

I am achieving this by writing below code:

```
 Map<String, Boolean> trueCountMap1 = map1.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue() == Boolean.TRUE)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        Map<String, Boolean> trueCountMap2 = map2.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue() == Boolean.TRUE)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        Map<String, Boolean> falseCountMap1 = map1.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue() == Boolean.FALSE)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        Map<String, Boolean> falseCountMap2 = map2.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue() == Boolean.FALSE)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        map1TrueMoreThanMap2True = (CollectionUtils.disjunction(trueCountMap1.entrySet(), trueCountMap2.entrySet())
                .size())/2;
        map1FalseMoreThanMap2False = (CollectionUtils
                .disjunction(falseCountMap1.entrySet(), falseCountMap2.entrySet()).size())/2;
```

**i think the above code is verbose. Is there a better way of doing it??**

Comment: That is pretty much what the [Collectors.partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-)  does, but in a better way.

Comment: I have read your description multiple times, including the code example and still have no idea of what you are trying to do. As far as I understood, the first disjunction is `("i2", True), ("i4", True), ("i3", True), ("i5", True)` and the second is `("i3", False), ("i2", False)`. On what basis do you assume that you can simply halve the size of the disjunction? The variable names suggest that you are assuming that this is the number of entries belonging to the first map, but that’s pure coincidence with your sample data. What if your `map2` contained `("i5", True)`?

Comment: @holger... what you understood and explained in your answer is absolutely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to know, how many entries of `map1` map to `true`  (resp. `false`) and differ from the entries of `map2`. This doesn’t work by halving the disjunction’s size. It would work when all keys are guaranteed to be the same, but in your example data, there are different keys, `"i4"` only present in `map1` and `"i5"` only present in `map2`, and it looks like pur coincidence that both map to the same value. As soon as either maps to a different value, your approach would fail.

It’s much simpler to straight-forwardly implement the “*how many entries of `map1` map to `true`  (resp. `false`) and differ from the entries of `map2`*” instead of dealing with set operations:

```
int map1TrueMoreThanMap2True   = (int)map1.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e ->  e.getValue() && !map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), false))
    .count();
int map1FalseMoreThanMap2False = (int)map1.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> !e.getValue() && map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), true))
    .count();
```

It’s possible to do this in one Stream operation, if you wish:

```
Map<Boolean,Long> result = map1.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() ^ map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), !e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting()));
int map1TrueMoreThanMap2True   = result.get(true).intValue();
int map1FalseMoreThanMap2False = result.get(false).intValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be very helpful if you can explain your one stream operation in detail.

Comment: Well, it straightforwardly says “for every entry of `map1` that maps to `true` (resp. `false`) *and* `map2` does not map to `true` (resp. `false`), count it”. It utilizes `Map.getOrDefault` to treat absent values like the nonmatching value. The second variant’s filter does not require a particular value in `map1`, but only that it is different to `map2`’s (the xor operator `^` is basically like `!=` for `boolean` values here). It again uses `getOrDefault` to map absent values to the opposite. It then partitions the result into two count for `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a method as such that utilises `partitioningBy` internally:

```
static Map<Boolean, Set<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>> partition(Map<String, Boolean> map){
      return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                   Collectors.toSet()));
}
```

Now, you can do:

```
Map<Boolean, Set<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>> firstResultSet = partition(map1);

Map<Boolean, Set<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>> secondResultSet = partition(map2);
```

Calling `firstResultSet.get(true)` will return a set of map entries where each entry key has a corresponding value of `true`.

Conversely calling `firstResultSet.get(false)` will return a set of map entries where each entry key has a corresponding value of `false`.

The same can be done to the `secondResultSet` map in order to retrieve the corresponding set of map entries.

Comment: But collecting into a `Set<String>` instead of `Set<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>>` would be enough, maintaining the `Boolean` that is the same for all entries in a partition is not needed…